# Override Bootstrap css rules

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple problem that is driving me insane. I want to override a CSS rule from bootstrap. By default, bootstrap assigns `position: relative` to elements with a class of `navbar`. I want my `navbar`s to be `position: absolute`.

From my research on similar questions, I have tried:

- Loading Bootstrap first and then my custom CSS file, as to override the rules there. Makes no difference
- Make it so that my rule has more specificity:

In Bootstrap's file, all they have is (from what I can tell):

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
}
```

So in mine, I have:

```
div .navbar.menu {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Makes no difference

- I even put !important in there (just to try it out, I wasn't going to leave it like that), no luck. I also tried throwing in random IDs and classes to the selector to no avail.

It works if I:

- Use inline styling (don't want to do this)
- Add the attribute using jQuery on DOM ready (don't want to do this)

Ill be glad to provide any more info if needed
Any ideas will be appreciated !

EDIT:

My HTML snippet (for loading the css)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">
```

The thing I am trying to target is here (its under body -> nav -> div):

```
<div class ="navbar menu">
```

I tried selecting it as `body nav div .container.menu` too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your css

```
 div .navbar.menu {
   position: absolute;
 }
```

the html structure would have to be

```
<div>
    <div class='navbar menu'>
    ....
    </div>
</div>
```

but if you have just this

```
<body>
    <div class='navbar menu'>
    ....
    </div>
</body>
```

your css has to be

```
 div.navbar.menu {
   position: absolute;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, can't you just do:

```
.navbar{
position:absolute;
top:#px;
left:#px;
width:100%;
}
```

like here: http://www.bootply.com/pcyQsgEQVP

Comment: also, I'm not positive what your intended outcome is, but adding "navbar-static-top" lets you stick the menu up top without any custom css

Comment: I am using navbar-fixed-top, but I am trying to move the links inside the navbar to a different position inside the container (if that makes sense) - thanks for the tip though !

Comment: ah. i'd be careful moving items around within the container using absolute positioning, but if it works for you, awesome. other ways include pull-right/left, navbar-right, as well as setting up columns within the navbar. if you hit issues, try those!